# Kotlin Take within Apply scope not working in android

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I have a nullable Int that I need to use to truncate a list with "take". But when I do this, the list stays the same.
Example:

```
var num: Int? = 1

var list = listOf("1", "2", "3")

// list remains as size 3
var newList = list.apply{
    num?.let {
        this.take(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal, because `take` doesn't modify the input list; it returns a new copy of the selected elements.

The simplest way to write this code is:

```
val newList = if (num != null) list.take(num) else list
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code isn't just that `take` returns a new list (that's true) but that you're using `apply` as scope function.  `apply` returns `this` and not the result of the lambda, so no matter what you do in the lambda, `newList` will always be `list`.

The proposed solution is a good one. If you're a fan of scope functions you can also do

```
val newList = num?.let { list.take(it) } ?: list
```

which is exactly 7 character shorter than

```
val newList = if (num != null) list.take(num) else list
```